Sequence diagram - modelling HTTP requests
For my school project, I need to create a sequence diagram. In that sequence diagram I have to represent an API call using simple JavaScript code (fetch() + then() for handling the response).
I'm confused, should I represent this as sync or async communication in a sequence diagram?
In one way, since the web browser is not blocked while waiting for a response I guess it should be async. But in another way, it waits for the response so it can be processed so it's blocked from executing which means is should be sync?

I tried google-ing this problem but didn't find any answers.

The fetch asynchronous (it leaves the local processor free), but your specific solution may require the fetch for any further processing. In sequence diagrams, asynchronous processes can be represented by multiple events occurring at the same time (at the same vertical position). E.g. if two different services were needed to fully render the dropdown, the browser would at once request from both of them, then both services (each with a separate lifeline) would respond in parallel (at the same vertical position but on different lifelines), as the browser waits for both to resolve.

An HTTP request that returns the response directly is synchronous. For an asynchronous communication, the server would have to send another message, e.g. via a WebSocket.

Thank you for helping me. One more question, since sync is a blocking call, does that mean that in my sequence diagram case web browser will be shown as "blocked" meaning no other action can be executed in browser untill it gets response? Thanks.

Http requests are never synchronous. Synchronous implies that the processor is busy; as soon as the processor is done writing the request payload to the network layer, it is no longer busy. The request may take any amount of time to reach some remote server, be processed by that server into a response, and for the response to return. The initial processor is not busy during any of this; the network request is an asynchronous process.

The fetch() API is promise-based and hence asynchronous. The then() method is invoked not synchronously, but asynchronously when the promise is fulfilled, i.e. the fetch() response finally arrives.
Therefore, the right way to model it, is the async call in the right diagram, although, one would expect that the message 4 is send from the end of the activation zone (like for message 3, except that life is going on on the browser side and other activity might start before that incoming message).
If however you use await fetch() instead of fetch().then() you would have the choice:  while technically, it's still asynchronous, de facto you'd wait for the promise to be completed before doing anything else, i.e. you behave as if it would be synchronous.  So in your modelling,  you could focus on your design intent, independently of how you implemented it.
